# TikZ-cd: How can we draw a border around multiple nodes?

Tags: tikz-cd, border

I am wondering if there is a way of drawing a border around a selected set of nodes in `tikz-cd`. There are some past threads for TikZ, and they are too complicated for me to comprehend. I would like to basically draw

[image: a drawing].

I can position the three nodes easily by following the `tikz-cd` manual; however, I did not see a way of drawing a shape around multiple nodes (around `a1` and `a2` here) there...

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small] 
& a_3 &\\  a_1 \arrow[rr] & & a_2 \arrow[ll,shift left] \end{tikzcd}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use the `fit` Ti*k*Z library by passing `fit=(A1) (A2)` as a `node` option, after aliasing the two nodes to be boxed `A1` and `A2`. The aliasing can be done in the `tikz-cd` matrix thanks to the `|...|` syntax that allows one to pass tokens when a Ti*k*Z matrix node is automatically constructed. The final drawings, once the involved nodes have been given convenient aliases, can be performed thanks to the `/tikz/execute at end picture` style.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep=small, row sep=small,
  /tikz/execute at end picture={
    \node (large) [rectangle, draw, fit=(A1) (A2)] {};
    \draw[->] (large) -- (A3);
  }]
               & |[alias=A3]| a_3 & \\[5ex]
|[alias=A1]| a_1 \arrow[rr] &     & |[alias=A2]| a_2 \arrow[ll, shift left]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With plain TikZ and `fit` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(-1,0) node (a1) {$a_1$}
(1,0) node (a2) {$a_2$}
(0,1.5) node (a3) {$a_3$};
\node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2)] (a12) {};
\draw[->] (a12)--(a3);
\draw[->] (a1.15)--(a2.165);
\draw[<-] (a1.-15)--(a2.-165);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```